# Microservice architecture and database design

Tags: database-design, architecture

I am designing a micro-services architecture for a solution that will span multiple modules that can work separately or can be pluggable according to the acquisition.
My problem of architectural / infra-data definition is in the following point: just as an example (not the real solution), let's consider it a complete solution for reservations management with the following modules:

Hotel Booking Module

Entertainment Reservation Module (various events: theater, musical shows etc)

Vehicle Reservation Module

Air Ticket Sale Module

Each module would have its own domain: integrations, rules and database of your domain, the problem I am trying to solve in this service / storage modeling is how to separate the common parts in a service bus and reuse it for all modules but without creating a single data model, example:
in all these modules I will have a user base (there will be other common points), what better approach to have a unique but independent user data storage to the models of each service module?

I thought about the following options:

1 - Have a service bus to manage users in a common database and each module would have a reference to the user's FK in their schema directly by the database.
Using this approach https://www.akadia.com/services/ora_references_constraint.html
But what is the impact of, for example, doing JOIN between schemas? Can it make it impossible?

2 - Have a service bus to manage users in a common database and would replicate the data via services for each module, each of which would have its own user base.
Problem would be several user bases within the same solution.

Each module has its own services and data models, I do not want to create a single storage model for all modules. It is not a large system with several parts, it is a solution with several independent but pluggable systems.

The first option seems better, but I'm not comfortable thinking about modern architecture.

What do you suggest about this architecture, a NoSQL solution would be more appropriate?

Any tip is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider Hotel Booking , Entertainment Reservation, Vehicle Reservation Module and Air Ticket Sale Module as individual microservices with their own domain, maybe there is room for another microservice that manages Users?

If so, then option 1 sounds like a better option though you have to be mindful of the communication method between the microservices. A synchronous call like REST over HTTP will reduce the overall availability of your microservices if not done properly. Maybe you can consider having a message based, asynchronous communication method to retrieve the Users information through a message broker.

I don't think a NoSQL database would help here since the issue is identifying the boundaries of the domain.